# Parameter "262144" (top-most attribute set) in Task Scheduler does not work (VBScript)

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, task-manager, vbscript, task-scheduler

Parameter `262144` (top-most attribute set) in Task Scheduler does not work. When creating a task to run a .vbs file, parameter `262144` does not work (does not open the window on top of others), although if you run it yourself, then everything works. With parameter `4096`, it runs on top of all windows, but then there will be an icon in the upper left of the window (which does not suit me).

Here's my script:

```
MsgBox "msg", vbOKOnly + vbInformation + 262144, "title"
```

I noticed that if I run it like this:

```
Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
Sound.URL = "\to\path"
Sound.Controls.play
MsgBox "msg", vbOKOnly + vbInformation + 262144, "title"
```

So the script is launched through the Task Scheduler on top of all windows...

P.S.

Please do not suggest making msgbox yourself, .HTA, etc. I want to solve exactly this problem.

Comment: @JaromandaX
You don't understand. I meant the icon at the top left in the corner of the window (where the title is)

Comment: What did you end up doing in your script?

Answer (score 1):

With the simple one-line MsgBox script, the `262144` flag sets the window as topmost of all the windows of the *current application* only (i.e. wscript.exe), which is not the same as `4096` (vbSystemModal).

However, you've discovered a nice little workaround that causes the `262144` flag to behave as vbSystemModal, but without the icon.

Either of the examples below will result in the message popping up over all other windows, as though you used vbSystemModal, but without any icon.

```
Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
Sound.URL = ""
MsgBox "Reminder", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation + 262144, "Reminder"
```

```
Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX")
Sound.Controls.Play
MsgBox "Reminder", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation + 262144, "Reminder"
```

P.S. If you do want to play a WAV file, it turns out that the line `Sound.Controls.Play` is not needed. The WAV file plays as soon as `Sound.URL` is assigned.